# Twitter fabric API: Sorting tweets based on location (nearest first)

Tags: android, sorting, twitter, tweets, twitter-fabric

So I am developing a lost and found app using Fabric API. It has a option to sort the collected tweets based on user's current location. I found the below way online to sort using a comparator. This however, doesn't seem to work and the before-sorting and after-sorting results are totally alike.

```
public class SortLocations implements Comparator<Tweet> {
    Double currLat;
    Double currLng;

    public SortLocations(Double currLat1, Double currLng1) {
        currLat = currLat1;
        currLng = currLng1;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(final Tweet tweet1, final Tweet tweet2) {
        double lat1 = 0, lon1 = 0, lat2 = 0, lon2 = 0, distanceToPlace1 = 0, distanceToPlace2 = 0;
        try {
            lat1 = tweet1.coordinates.getLatitude();
            lon1 = tweet1.coordinates.getLongitude();

            lat2 = tweet2.coordinates.getLatitude();
            lon2 = tweet2.coordinates.getLongitude();

            distanceToPlace1 = distance(currLat, currLng, lat1, lon1);
            distanceToPlace2 = distance(currLat, currLng, lat2, lon2);
        } catch (Exception E) {
            Log.d("No coordinates", "");
        }
        return (int) (distanceToPlace1 - distanceToPlace2);
    }

    public double distance(double fromLat, double fromLon, double toLat, double toLon) {
        double radius = 6378137;   // approximate Earth radius, *in meters*
        double deltaLat = toLat - fromLat;
        double deltaLon = toLon - fromLon;
        double angle = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(
                Math.pow(Math.sin(deltaLat / 2), 2) +
                        Math.cos(fromLat) * Math.cos(toLat) *
                                Math.pow(Math.sin(deltaLon / 2), 2)));
        return radius * angle;
    }
}
```

This is how the class is used in my activity

```
Collections.sort(tweetsSortedByLocation, new SortLocations(currLat, currLng));
```

Where tweetsSortedByLocation is of type List. Any help is really appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might suggest a slightly different approach that will make your life a little easier without losing any computation time.

Your current solution is likely n + n log(n) time: n for adding Tweets to the Collection, and then n log(n) for sorting. If you use a PriorityQueue (implemented as min-heap in Java) instead of a regular List (as I assume tweetsSortedByLocation is), then it'll sort as you add to it, giving you n log(n) time: n for each element and log(n) for each insertion (think binary search).

You can use a PriorityQueue like so (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

```
PriorityQueue<Tweet> tweetsSortedByLocation = new PriorityQueue<>(10, new SortLocations(currLat, currLong));
tweetsSortedByLocation.add(new Tweet());    // Or however you add them now
```

You could also inline the Comparator, but using SortLocations is better.

Now as to why nothing changes when you sort, that means compare() must be returning 0 every time. That would happen if the difference between the two distances you calculate is less than 1. Look at the integer cast on this line:

```
return (int) (distanceToPlace1 - distanceToPlace2);
```

If distanceToPlace1 and distanceToPlace2 are no more than 1 in difference, that integer cast brings it to 0, which, in how compare must be implemented, means equality. (See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html.) So, try this instead (to sort least distance first (i.e. asc by distance)):

```
if (distanceToPlace1 < distanceToPlace2) {
    return -1;
} else if (distanceToPlace1 > distanceToPlace2) {
    return 1;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

I hope that fixes your problem

Comment: Thanks for the response Zach!. Really appreciate your comprehensive solution.